# Removing elements in jQuery results in error

Tags: jquery

I have a page with lots of tables, each with a link inside. I had to check if they are dead or not so i build this code:

```
    function UrlExists(url)
    {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', url, false);
        http.send();
        return http.status!=404;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("table[id^='row']").each(function(){
            if(!UrlExists($(this).children("a:nth-child(2)").attr('href')))
                $(this).remove();
        })
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to work and even the error console is not helpful:

```
Error: ($(parentElement) || document.body).getElementsByTagName is not a function
Source File: http://..../js/prototype.js
Line: 835
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: you are using `jQuery` and yet `XMLHttpRequest`? Limitation from legacy code? :o

Comment: @SiGanteng: :) I just copy-paste the functions for my requirements without looking what they are about.

Comment: are you using jQuery or Prototype.js?

Comment: *Source File: http://..../js/prototype.js
Line: 835
Where I am wrong?* `:'((((((`

Comment: @UmairP the tag is `jQuery`, so...

Comment: Ok this question must be closed. I am editing someone else's code I didnt knew about frameowrk like prototype.js. I just that might be a native JS code. The problem is because of contradictory usage of $.

Comment: You have an answer with the correct diagnostic (at least it seems) from Esalija. So no need to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error is from a file called `prototype.js`, I am gonna guess `$` is owned by prototype not jQuery.

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("table[id^='row']").each(function(){
        if(!UrlExists($(this).children("a:nth-child(2)").attr('href')))
            $(this).remove();
    })
});
```

Comment: Doesn't help. I don't think it is possible to load two frameworks in one file with name conflict?

Comment: @Shubham But does it show the new code? Are you sure you're not just using cached page? If you are sure your page is not using cached code then your code didn't cause the error in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I did Shift+F5 to reload everything.

Comment: Oh man how you are so sure? :) I just noticed that a variable `children` has been declared where the error has been pointed.

Comment: @Shubham What does that mean? If your error message changed, please show it as requested. Also, what jQuery version are you using?

Comment: `var children = ($(parentElement) || document.body).getElementsByTagName('*');` This line: I mean when i use the function children() it conflicts with this variable.

Comment: @Shubham that doesn't make any sense. Where do you see this line? In prototype library code? If you just linked to the page it would be over already :d

Comment: @Shubham I cannot find any prototype version that has code `var children`

Comment: Don't mind. Thanks for the help. I just removed that library, which was seemingly good for nothing. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Shubham no problem, for that matter I couldn't find any prototype version that has original error code